# Java wildcard expansion

Tags: java, apache-commons-io

I need to expand wildcards in a filepath to get a list of files that match the filepath.
I used commons-io from apache:

```
protected File[] wildcardResolution(File f) {
    File dir = f.getParentFile();
    FileFilter fileFilter = new WildcardFileFilter(f.getName());
    return dir.listFiles(fileFilter);
}
```

The problem is that it expands only `*` or `?` wildcards but not `**` wildcards, so:
/usr/**/*.xml doesn't match `all files with extension .xml, in any subfolder of /usr`.

**How can i get `**` wildcard expansion to work properly?**

*Thanks*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with [File.listFiles](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FileFilter%29) is that it does not list recursively.

You can use [FileUtils.iterateFiles or listFiles](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#iterateFiles%28java.io.File,%20org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter,%20org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter%29). Which uses one pattern for the files and one pattern for the directories. Which is not exactly the same as one globbing expression:

```
Iterator iterateFiles = FileUtils.iterateFiles(
  new File("."), new WildcardFileFilter("*.xml"), TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE);
while(iterateFiles.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(iterateFiles.next());
}
```